# Candy OpenFire Jboss Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, jboss, xmpp, openfire

I installed Openfire, set everything according to doc in candy documentation.

Set apache server in front of Jboss and Openfire.

edited etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file :

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /http-bind http://ip_of_machine:7070/http-bind
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://ip_of_machine:7070/http-bind

ProxyPass /myjavawebapp http://ip_of_machine:8080/myjavawebapp
ProxyPassReverse /myjavawebapp http://ip_of_machine:8080/myjavawebapp
```

run

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect true
```

after this if  I go over browser

```
http://ip_of_machine/myjavawebapp
```

I see my app, and if I go

```
http://ip_of_machine/http-bind/
```

I get this page

```
 Openfire HTTP Binding Service
```

my code for init of candy is like this

```
     Candy.init('http-bind/', {
                            core: { debug: false },
                            view: { resources: '../res/' }
                    });

                    Candy.Core.connect();
```

I am not sure how to connect with my user/pass for openfire. I tried different user/pass combo, I tried to use different Candy.Core.connect config, but with no luck.

I can connect from pidgin and any other client to OpenFire, but for that I am using port 5222

When I put some value in Candy.Core.connect (with only one parameter), I am asked only for user name, I enter it, and after that it looks like infinite loop of request to http-bind, which every time return same thing

```
 Openfire HTTP Binding Service
```

I am not sure if I missed some setting with OpenFire, or set something wrong with Apache, or is somethng wrong with javascript code, or something else.

Any idea, suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. There was error in my apache setting and javascript  code

first I set apache conf like this

```
ProxyPass /myjavawebapp http://ip_of_machine:8080/myjavawebapp
ProxyPassReverse /myjavawebapp http://ip_of_machine:8080/myjavawebapp

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http-bind/ http://ip_of_machine:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

after this I  modified javascript candy code like this

```
Candy.init('/http-bind/', {
            core: { debug: true ,autojoin: ['muc@conference.ip_of_machine']}
            ,
            view: { resources: '../res/' }
  });

Candy.Core.connect();
```

I used username as

```
myusername@ip_of_machine
```

and password for my user, and it all worked :)